# Move several tables from remote database to another

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have to move several tables from one remote database to another in PostgreSQL.

From my understanding the only way of doing it is via `pg_dump`.

```
pg_dump -h <source_db_host> -U <source_db_user> -d <source_db_name> -f database_dump.sql

psql -h <target_db_host> -U <target_db_user> -d <target_db_name> -f database_dump.sql
```

However, it fails as the schema in destination database is different from the one in source, so I receive the error message that particular schema is not exist in source db.

Is there a way to change the destination schema?

Is there any other, easier option for transferring the datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_dump` has no option to suppress schema names. (That could lead to all kinds of complications.) Old versions operated with setting the search path, but nowadays, table names are schema-qualified.

**If possible**, you could rename the schema in the source DB suitably before dumping. (And later rename back.)

**Or** create the missing schema in the target DB first:

```
CREATE SCHEMA old_schema;
```

Then use the commands you have. After restoring all tables you can simply move tables to a different schema:

```
ALTER TABLE old_schema.table1 SET SCHEMA new_schema;
```

That's a cheap operation (unless the two schemas use a different `TABLESPACE` - which they wouldn't by default.) [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

> `SET SCHEMA`
>
> This form moves the table into another schema. Associated indexes,
> constraints, and sequences owned by table columns are moved as well.

Drop the staging schema `old_schema` when done.

**Or** you hack the dump with an editor of your choice to change the schema. I would do it with `vim` using the `\s` (substitute) command. Take care of auxiliary objects and keep references intact. Here is an example with `sed`:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146760/how-force-pg-dump-to-not-include-scheme-name-for-each-objects-in-ddl

There are many other workarounds. Related:

- [I want to restore the database with a different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4191653/939860)